# How to handle list of list in Spring Expression Language

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have POJO that contains some basic attributes and a List of another POJO (say Customers POJO), the Customers POJO in turn contains a list of another POJO (say Addresses POJO).

I am able to access all the attributes for all entries in the Customers POJO List using Spring Expression Language 'collection projection' operator for accessing the Employees `{#Customers.![customerName]}`, `{#Customers.![customerAge]}`, etc. and its works fine.

But can some one please let me know how to access all the List entries of Addresses POJO under each Customer POJO List?

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that Spring EL not support nested list projection, so we have to do it by ourselves.

Actually, the collection projection is same as Java8's map, and collection selection equals to Java8's filter.

By using Java8 stream, we can do it through `flatmap` and `collect`:

```
#{customers.stream()
  .map(Customer::getAddress)
  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toList())}
```